# what is the better between them in speed (using asm or without), and the speed actually deserve

Tags: c, optimization

In my case I want the better speed.
which one is better between them in speed.

**For example:**

```
int n=0;
__asm {
MOV n, 100
INC n
ADD n, 100
}
printf("%d\n", n);
```

**Or**

```
int n=0;
n = 100;
n++;
n += 100;
printf("%d\n", n);
```

And I'm used the following code to know what better between them, but they will not give me a result to show me what's better.

```
double duration;
clock_t start, end;
start = clock();

// code here

end = clock();
duration = (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("%f\n", duration );
```

Comment: check using the system clock ticks that needed for them to work to check which is faster...

Comment: @No Idea For Name: can you please give me an excerpt about using what you say

Comment: I'd hope the compiler is smart enough to convert the latter into `push 201` instead of calculating `n` then pushing `n`.

Comment: @LionKing sorry can't right now, but a 1 minute in google will find it no problem

Answer (score 1):

Besides measuring clock cycles you can also use disassembly to determine exactly what the compiler chose

basically in such a small code the compiler would most likely make the correct choices for faster and smaller code (especially if optimized for speed) and in that case it is prefered to use C instead of asm for code portability and the avoidance of bugs when you make small changes

If the compiler did not choose the same approach as your assembly i would try to figure out why. It might be very important.

Answer (score 0):

You could measure the performance difference of your two approaches with cpu cycles. Try this, instead of clock:

```
inline uint64 getCycles() {
    uint64 cycles;

    __asm__ __volatile__("rdtsc" : "=A" (cycles));

    return cycles;
}
```

Comment: What is the `uint64` header ? and where can I enter the code?

Comment: uint64 is an integer of size 8: typedef unsigned long long uint64;

Comment: `inline assembler syntax error in 'opcode'; found ( `, I'm using Visual studio 2010

Comment: Oh, i should have noticed it from your code above. My example is for Linux/GCC. Try this for windows: #include <intrin.h>
uint64_t getCycles(){return __rdtsc();}

Comment: Also note that this is available ONLY on `x86` where `x > 4` i.e. on the Pentium processor and newer.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not going to be much difference between two versions. The only difference could be that you may write asm code that best fit to your CPU but compiler may write a general one.

If you had memory operations,if statements,for loops there could be a difference.

Loops,cache issues and system calls are biggest time consumers.

I would say that it is wiser to write C code for such a simple case for readability.

You can write clean C code and get best possible performance with other means: Using special hardware (ex: GPU), better algorithm, re-define the problem, better compiler usage....